# Добавление файла на сайт из прямой ссылки на скачивание

Tags: javascript

Всем привет.
Мне нужно файл, на который есть прямая ссылка на скачивание, передать в  или в FormData для дальнейшей загрузки файла на другой сервер.
Подскажите, реально ли это сделать?
Заранее спасибо.
Пример файла https://www.google.ru/logos/doodles/2018/world-cup-2018-day-12-6225439109414912-s.png

Comment: передать в input type=file или в FormData

Comment: Через js будет костыль, но возможно... в виде base64. Но проще передать ссылку серверу и уже на сервере скачать.

Comment: К сожалению доступа на сервер нет, поэтому ссылку ему передать не могу. Любой костыль мне подойдёт. Можно, пожалуйста, чуть подробнее про base64?

Comment: И можно ли будет в виде base64 отправлять не только картинки, а любые файлы?

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64

Comment: Александр, я понимаю что такое base64, но не могу понять как применить это к своей задаче.

Comment: Грузите удаленную картинку в канвас выгружаете от туда base64 и отправляете его на сервер. Вот тут пример https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34972072/how-to-send-image-to-server-with-http-post-in-javascript-and-store-base64-in-mon